# Multi checkbox post proplem

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I wanna check same exist  database, but doesn't work the $check. What's wrong ı cannot find.
 ı taking this error when post;

```
error 1-Members not added :(
Mysql error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''459' at line 1
error 2- 459 memb_id already in databese, try again!
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $row_data = array();
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $row=>$Name) {
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($Name);
$memb_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['memb_id'][$row]);
$memb_srnm=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['memb_srnm'][$row]); 
$kur_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kur_id'][$row]);

    $row_data = array("'$memb_id'", "'$memb_srnm'", "'$kur_id'");
}


if (!empty($row_data)) {
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basvurular WHERE memb_id='$memb_id");
if (mysql_affected_rows()  ){
                 echo '<h4 class="alert_error"><strong>'.ss($memb_id).'</strong>  already in databese, try again! </h4>';
                 header('Location: index.php');

        } else {

            $query = 'INSERT INTO basvurular (memb_id, memb_srnm, basvur_kurid) VALUES (' .implode(',', $row_data) . ')';
        }


if (mysql_query($query)){

    echo '<h4 class="alert_success"> <label style="color: blue; font-size: 26px; font-weight: bold;"><img style="width: 4%" src="images/pers2.png" alt=""/>-'.mysql_affected_rows().'- </label> Succesfull  :)  </h4>';
    header('Location: index.php');          


}else{
    echo '<h4 class="alert_error">Members not added :( <br> Mysql Error:'.mysql_error().'</h4>';

    return false;}
}


?>
    <article  class="module width_3_quarter" style="padding-bottom: 10px; width: 95%">
    <header>
        <div style="float:right;font-size:14px;font-weight: bold; padding:10px"></div>

        <h3 class="tabs_involved">POST SELECTED</h3>
    </header>
    <div class="tab_container">


    <?php


$query = query("SELECT * FROM members  INNER JOIN kurumlar ON kurumlar.kur_id = members.kur_id WHERE kurumlar.kur_id=' ".$_SESSION["kur_id"]." ' && ceza=0 ORDER BY memb_id DESC");
if (mysql_affected_rows()){
?>

<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
<?php echo '<form action="" method="post" name="frm" onsubmit="return check">
<table class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0"> '; ?>
<thead> 
    <tr>
         <th><a style="text-decoration: none;font-size:14px;font-weight: bold; color: blue" href="javascript:void(0);" id="link" onclick="slct()">All Select</a></th>
        <th align= "left" >ID Number</th> <th></th> 
        <th align= "left" >USER NAME</th><label style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;float:right " ><input style="color: red" type="submit" name="post" value="Selected Post"></label>

         <th></th> 
        <th></th> 
    </tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
    <?php

    while ($row = row($query)){
     ?>

             <tr>

         <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"  id="checkbox[]" ></td>
                <td><?php echo ss($row["membName"]);?></td><td><input name="memb_id[]" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo ss($row["memb_id"]);?>"></td>
                <td><?php echo ss($row["memb_srnm"]);?></td><td><input name="memb_srnm[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ss($row["memb_srnm"]);?>"></td>
                <td><input name="kur_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ss($_SESSION["kur_id"]);?>"></td>            
            </tr> 
                <?php }?>
        </tbody>    

        <?php echo '</table></form>'; ?>


        </div>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <h4 class="alert_warning">Nobody Here :(( </h4>
        <?php }?>
    </div>

    </article>
```

Comment: @Daedalus Yes you can, mysql will automatically convert.

Comment: So, at a minimum, you have a poorly formatted query.  have you tried to fix it or find ourt what data is missing that is causing the problem.  Also, not part of this question, but you do realize your `header()` redirection will not work right? You can't send output to the browser and then try to redirect.

Comment: @Barmar My bad, then.

Comment: Just a few comments: You realize that the foreach loop will just reset the variables inside the loop everytime, and that the previous iterations are not stored in any way? Next, you first do an echo and then use `header()`, that won't work. And for the error that you get, it seems that you are trying to add an `memb_id` that is already used and this might be a `UNIQUE` index? And the if statement after the `SELECT` query might have the wrong behaviour, as it means, in general, something different.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a quote on this line:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basvurular WHERE memb_id='$memb_id'");
```

Also, to check whether a `SELECT` query returned any rows, you should use `mysql_num_rows()`, not `mysql_affected_rows()` -- the latter is only for queries that modify tables.

You should also check that the query is successful:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM basvurular WHERE memb_id='$memb_id")
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Barmar, ı fixed but same false :459 memb_id already in databese, try again!

Comment: You need to check for errors from `mysql_query()`. You do it for `$query`, but not for `$check`.

Comment: I change code this way; if (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0 ){
                 echo '<h4 class="alert_error"><strong>'.ss($memb_id).'</strong>  already in databese, try again! </h4>';
                 header('Location: index.php');

        } else {

            $query = 'INSERT INTO basvurular (memb_id, memb_srnm, basvur_kurid) VALUES (' .implode(',', $row_data) . ')';
        }


again same false> 459 memb_id already in databese, try again!

Comment: ı'm try the post another memmbers but taking same false.

Comment: I can't read what you wrote, you should add it to your question, and please try to format it readably, with proper indentation.

Comment: I have many members belong to different departments..I defined kurumlar for departments and I give to mission members single select or multiselect with checkbox. above gives error when I post... so sorry my English is not so good, as far as I know I'm trying to tell

Comment: If you add your new code, nicely formatted, to the question, maybe I'll be able to help you.